# What is the old term, or terms, for "designer stubble"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Wikipedia has this to say about it:

> **Designer stubble** is a short growth of a man's facial hair that became popular in the 1980s. This style was worn and reinvented by
>   singer George Michael, actor Don Johnson and, in the 2010s, singers
>   Craig David and Jason Derulo and was adopted by many others including
>   Tom Cruise who restarted this trend among his Hollywood peers &
>   members of the music industry after attending the Grammy Awards in
>   2005. Several companies manufacture beard trimmers designed to maintain the designer stubble look, being created by short trimming of
>   the beard to (typically) 1 to 3mm designer stubble is distinct from
>   five o'clock shadow which is the much lighter, stiffer growth which is
>   the first sign of the return of the beard after shaving.

Here's the picture they provide:

[image: Here's the picture they provide:]

This type of look has existed since time immemorial, which leads me to believe that there must have been a term for it prior to the 1980's.

What was it?

Comment: Day-old beard??

Comment: It certainly _existed_ when a man hadn't bothered/been able to shave for a few days, but as far as I know the look had never been deliberately cultivated before the 1980s. You would just say he was unshaven.

Comment: I assume you are aware that the term 'designer stubble' is ironic: a joke at the expense of people who find style in what had previously considered neglect of personal appearance.

Answer (score 3):

from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/th/class/26824) thesaurus:

**bristle**  ~1300

> the short hairs on the face of men when thickened and
>   stiffened…

**whisker** ~1600

> The hair that grows on an adult man's face; formerly commonly applied
>   to that on the upper lip, now… plural: usually collective

**stubble**  1596

> collective singular. transferred. A rough surface or short growth
>   likened to the ‘stubble’ of grain, esp. the short bristly growth on a
>   man's face

**five o'clock shadow** 1937

> used attributively in five o'clock shadow (see quot.1937),
>   five-o'clock tea (colloquial shortened a five o'clock).Time 11 Oct. ‘5
>   o'clock Shadow’—that unsightly beard growth which appears prematurely
>   at about 5 P.M., looks bad.